# Find $\frac{(a+bi)^2}{c+di}-\frac{1}{a+ci}-\frac{1+i}{13i}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I must find the value of

$$\frac{(a+bi)^2}{c+di}-\frac{1}{a+ci}-\frac{1+i}{13i}$$

a) by knowing that the absolue value of $a+bi$ is $5$ and one of its arguments its between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

> and $b-a=1$

b)the square of $c+di$ is $-5-12i$ and $c<0$

I don't know if I need to consider items $a$ and $b$ together or separately. What I know how to do is that $(a+bi)^2 = |a+bi|^2$ but I don't now how to use the other informations.

Comment: The square of a complex number is not, in general, equal to its magnitude squared.

Comment: assuming a,b,c,d are integers, (a,b) is either (3,4) or (4,3) but there is no way of telling. is there more info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (b), we are given that the square of $c+id$ is $(c+id)^2=(c^2-d^2)+i2cd=-5-i12$.  Thus, we have the two equations $d^2-c^2=5$ and $cd=-6$, which under the condition $c<0$, has the solution $c=-2$ and $d=3$.

From (a) we are given is that $|a+ib|=5$, which implies that $a^2+b^2=25$, and that the argument of $a+ib$ is between $0$ and $\pi /2$, which implies that both $a$ and $b$ are positive, and $b=1+a$.  Thus, we get $a=3$ and $b=4$.

Now, just plug into the expression of interest!

Comment: sorry,I updated my question

Comment: OK.  Modified accordingly.  Let me know if I can improve the answer. I just want to give the best possible answer I can give you.

Answer (score 0):

let $$ a + ib = 5e^{it}, (c + di)^2 = -5 - 12i = 13e^{2is}, \, 0 < t < \pi/2< s < \pi.$$ 
you can verify that $$\cos s = -\frac{2}{\sqrt {13}}, \sin s = \frac{3}{\sqrt {13}} .$$

i am going to take one of the square roots  $$c + di = \sqrt{13}e^{is} = -2 + 3i $$

now i am stuck. are you sure the problem is well posed?

$\bf edit:$  the constraint $b - a= 1$ translates to $$\sin t -  \cos t=\frac 15 $$ together with $0 < t < \pi/2$ shows that $$\sin t =\frac 45, \cos t = \frac 35, a = 3, b = 4. $$

let us evaluate 
$$\begin{align}\frac{(a+bi)^2}{c+di}-\frac{1}{a+ci}-\frac{1+i}{13i} &=
\frac{(3 + 4i)^2}{-2 + 3i} - \frac{1}{3 -2i} - \frac{1+i}{13}\\
&=\frac{-7+4i}{-2 + 3i} - \frac{1}{3 -2i} - \frac{1+i}{13}\\
&=\frac{5+47i}{13i} - \frac{1+i}{13}\\
&= \frac{46}{13} + \frac{4i}{13}
\end{align}$$

Comment: sorry,I updated my question